# Please help me learn UML by analysis and design of a simple example, and then develop based on them

Tags: .net, uml

I'm currently studying UML....

Actualy need a simple example that start using UML for analysis and design it and then based on them start developing it by using .net.

Do you know any downloadable tutorial package which has analysis and design documentations beside its .net code?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Sparx's Enterprise Architect tool for a long time. They have a great UML 2.0 tutorial on their site: http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/index.html. Their tool is one of the best in the market, and it is not very expensive (I am not working at Sparx :)). You can download the trial version for 30 days.

For the .NET code? UML and .NET are two different things, there is no such a thing UML for .NET.